# Who called the event / observer in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

Eg I have a `block` that is on the `page` to edit the purchase order, both the editing `page` of the order as the `block` passes through the event sales_order_load_after when obeserver the event can not know what they spent for the event, if it was `page` or `block`.

How to know who called or went by event?

I have a fraud clearsales module, this module is on the order page to check I just click on the button analyze, when I click on it, it passes the event "sales_order_load_after" need to know who is passing by the magnitude of the event is ClearSale or page, I know that the two are going through the event as a test print.

[image]

**config.xml:**

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <ceicom_managesale>
                        <class>ceicom_managesale/observer</class>
                        <method>someMethod</method>
                    </ceicom_managesale>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_load_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

**Observer:**

```
<?php

class Ceicom_ManageSale_Model_Observer
{
    public function someMethod($observer)
    {
        echo("teste");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some concrete examples or code to your question to clarify what you're asking? on a side note: events are, as far as I know, rarely called from a block, only from controllers and models.

Comment: I added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events like `*_load_after` have no information where or by whom they were called.

But using request object you can get area, mudule, controller and action name and check them as you want.

```
    $oArea           = Mage::app()->getArea();
    $oRequest        = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $sModuleName     = $oRequest->getModuleName();
    $sControllerName = $oRequest->getControllerName();
    $sAtionName      = $oRequest->getActionName();
```

But you will have problem if some model (in your case `sales_order`) can be called twice on the same page.